# List<NameValuePair> to JSON Object

Tags: android, node.js, express, json

So here I have a basic array of NameValuePair.

```
List<NameValuePair> myList;
myList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
myList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "良好"));
myList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
myList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
```

How do I convert this to an array of JSON object? I am writing an application in nodejs using express. I have to specify the list as charset UTF-8. Only way to do that I believe is to convert the list to JSON object.

Currently, I am passing the list directly like this:

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

The problem with this is that nodejs can't interpret any characters except English characters. So if I change the list to JSON object, I can specify the header and charset, then express can interpret the characters properly.

So basically, How do I convert this List myList to an array of JSON object?

Thanks. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("username", "良好");
obj.put("email", email);
obj.put("password", password);
```

or

```
(JSONObject)JSONSerializer.toJSON(yourNameValue pair);
```

you can find its Api here http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/json/JSONObject.html